# ajax request (from localhost) to angel.co api not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I'm playing around with the Angel.co API, and am trying to do my first request. For some reason nothing shows up in my console when I hit the button on my html.

Any help much appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
$("#btn").click( function (){

$.ajax({
    url:"https://api.angel.co/1/search/slugs?query=yidio&callback=?",
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'JSONP',
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('body').append( "Name: " + data );
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working fine

Access like `data.id`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click( function (){
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.angel.co/1/search/slugs?query=yidio&callback=?",
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'JSONP',
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data)
              $('body').append("Name: " + data.name + '</br>');
              $('body').append("id: " + data.id + '</br>');
              $('body').append("type: " + data.type + '</br>');
              $('body').append("url: " + data.url + '</br>');
          }
      });
   }); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/789/)

Comment: @MaxF Glad to help you,after some time accept as answer

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the button event handler, can you see anything?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>GET JSON SHIT</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
 
</ul>


<button id="btn">GET ID</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @MaxF i did not see your button html code,so post that too

Comment: <button id="btn">GET ID</button>

Comment: Works now, wasn`t working because I skipped document ready I guess. Thanks!